# RestTemplate: How to send URL and query parameters together

Tags: java, resttemplate, url-parameters, query-string, path-parameter

I am trying to pass path param and query params in a URL but I am getting a weird error. Below is the code.

```
    String url = "http://test.com/Services/rest/{id}/Identifier"
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("id", "1234");
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
                                        .queryParam("name", "myName");
    String uriBuilder = builder.build().encode().toUriString();
    restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder , HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity,
                    class_p, params);
```

and my url is becoming `http://test.com/Services/rest/%7Bid%7D/Identifier?name=myName`

What should I do to make it work? I am expecting `http://test.com/Services/rest/{id}/Identifier?name=myName` so that params will add id to the url.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

I would use `buildAndExpand` from `UriComponentsBuilder` to pass all types of URI parameters.

For example:

```
String url = "http://test.com/solarSystem/planets/{planet}/moons/{moon}";

// URI (URL) parameters
Map<String, String> urlParams = new HashMap<>();
urlParams.put("planet", "Mars");
urlParams.put("moon", "Phobos");

// Query parameters
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
        // Add query parameter
        .queryParam("firstName", "Mark")
        .queryParam("lastName", "Watney");

System.out.println(builder.buildAndExpand(urlParams).toUri());
/**
 * Console output:
 * http://test.com/solarSystem/planets/Mars/moons/Phobos?firstName=Mark&lastName=Watney
 */

restTemplate.exchange(builder.buildAndExpand(urlParams).toUri() , HttpMethod.PUT,
        requestEntity, class_p);

/**
 * Log entry:
 * org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate Created PUT request for "http://test.com/solarSystem/planets/Mars/moons/Phobos?firstName=Mark&lastName=Watney"
 */
```

Comment: But "UriComponentsBuilder"  class is not available in Spring 3. is there any alternative solution for Spring 3?

Answer (score 22):

An issue with the answer from *Michal Foksa* is that it adds the query parameters first, and then expands the path variables. If query parameter contains parenthesis, e.g. `{foobar}`, this will cause an exception.

The safe way is to expand the path variables first, and then add the query parameters:

```java
String url = "http://test.com/Services/rest/{id}/Identifier";
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("id", "1234");
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
        .buildAndExpand(params)
        .toUri();
uri = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromUri(uri)
        .queryParam("name", "myName")
        .build()
        .toUri();
restTemplate.exchange(uri , HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, class_p);
```

Answer (score 6):

One-liner using TestRestTemplate.exchange function with parameters map.

```
restTemplate.exchange("/someUrl?id={id}", HttpMethod.GET, reqEntity, respType, ["id": id])
```

The params map initialized like this is a **groovy** initializer*

Comment: have you tried with path variable .Here your example demonstrate with query param and question was raised with  respect to path param.

Answer (score 3):

```
String url = "http://test.com/Services/rest/{id}/Identifier";
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("id", "1234");
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
        .buildAndExpand(params)
        .toUri();
uri = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromUri(uri)
        .queryParam("name", "myName")
        .build()
        .toUri();
restTemplate.exchange(uri , HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, class_p);
```

> The safe way is to expand the path variables first, and then add the query parameters:

For me this resulted in duplicated encoding, e.g. a space was decoded to %2520 (space -> %20 -> %25).

I solved it by:

```
String url = "http://test.com/Services/rest/{id}/Identifier";
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("id", "1234");
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);
uriComponentsBuilder.uriVariables(params);
Uri uri = uriComponentsBuilder.queryParam("name", "myName");
        .build()
        .toUri();
restTemplate.exchange(uri , HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, class_p);
```

Essentially I am using `uriComponentsBuilder.uriVariables(params);` to add path parameters. The documentation says:

> ... In contrast to UriComponents.expand(Map) or buildAndExpand(Map), this method is useful when you need to supply URI variables without building the UriComponents instance just yet, or perhaps pre-expand some shared default values such as host and port. ...

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#uriVariables-java.util.Map-

Answer (score 1):

Since version 5.3 you can use this API to do this.

```
RequestEntity.post(urlString, urlParam1, urlParam2).headers(...).body(requestBody);
```

> public static RequestEntity.BodyBuilder post(String uriTemplate,
> Object... uriVariables)
> Create an HTTP POST builder with the given string base uri template.

At the docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/RequestEntity.html#post-java.net.URI-

Or

```
template.exchange(..., uriVariables)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do that is:

```
String url = "http://test.com/Services/rest/{id}/Identifier"

UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).build();
uriComponents = uriComponents.expand(Collections.singletonMap("id", "1234"));
```

and then adds the query params.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code, I had to pass two values in the respective placeholders while making the query parameter.

```
String queryParam = "Key=Project_{ProdjectCode}_IN_{AccountCode}"

Map<String, String> queryParamMap = new HashMap<>();
queryParamMap.put("ProjectCode","Project1");
queryParamMap.put("AccountCode","Account1");

UriComponents builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://myservice.com/accountsDetails").query(queryParam).buildAndExpand(queryParamMap);

restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET,httpEntity,MyResponse.class);
```

Above code will make a GET call to url
http://myservice.com/accountsDetails?Key=Project_Project1_IN_Account1