# Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have REST server on Spring-boot 2.2.1 connected with mysql and JavaFX client using Spring-web 5.2.3. I would like to send http request from client to server. For method GET works great, but for POST does not work good.

My entity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity(name = "CANDIDATES")
public class Candidate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String lastname;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Education education;

    private String placeOfResidence;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "JOIN_VOTERESULTS_CANDIDATES",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CANDIDATES_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "VOTERESULTS_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")}
    )
    private List<VoteResult> voteResults;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ELECTION_LISTS_ID")
    private ElectionList electionList;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ELECTORAL_PARTIES_ID")
    private ElectoralParty electoralParty;
}
```

The CandidateDto has got the same variables. Here is my controller for POST:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createCandidate")
public void createCandidate(@Valid CandidateDto candidateDto) {
    service.createCandidate(candidateDto);
}
```

Here is method for creating this object in client and send POST request with body to server:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());

URI url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(URL + "/createCandidate")
    .queryParam("id", candidate.getId())
    .queryParam("name", candidate.getName())
    .queryParam("lastname", candidate.getLastname())
    .queryParam("education", candidate.getEducation())
    .queryParam("placeOfResidence", candidate.getPlaceOfResidence())
    .queryParam("voteResults", candidate.getVoteResults())
    .queryParam("electionList", candidate.getElectionList())
    .queryParam("electoralParty", candidate.getElectoralParty()).build().encode().toUri();

restTemplate.postForObject(url, null, Candidate.class);
```

Everything works great when I delete queryParams with electoralParty, electionList and voteResults.But with these params I have errors in server:

```
Field error in object 'candidateDto' on field 'education': rejected value [zawodowe]; codes [typeMismatch.candidateDto.education,typeMismatch.education,typeMismatch.com.pk.electionappserver.domain.Education,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [candidateDto.education,education]; arguments []; default message [education]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.pk.electionappserver.domain.Education' for property 'education'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.pk.electionappserver.domain.Education] for value 'zawodowe'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.pk.electionappserver.domain.Education.zawodowe]
Field error in object 'candidateDto' on field 'electionList': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.candidateDto.electionList,typeMismatch.electionList,typeMismatch.com.pk.electionappserver.domain.dto.ElectionListDto,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [candidateDto.electionList,electionList]; arguments []; default message [electionList]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.pk.electionappserver.domain.dto.ElectionListDto' for property 'electionList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.pk.electionappserver.domain.dto.ElectionListDto' for property 'electionList': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
Field error in object 'candidateDto' on field 'electoralParty': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.candidateDto.electoralParty,typeMismatch.electoralParty,typeMismatch.com.pk.electionappserver.domain.dto.ElectoralPartyDto,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [candidateDto.electoralParty,electoralParty]; arguments []; default message [electoralParty]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.pk.electionappserver.domain.dto.ElectoralPartyDto' for property 'electoralParty'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.pk.electionappserver.domain.dto.ElectoralPartyDto' for property 'electoralParty': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
Field error in object 'candidateDto' on field 'voteResults': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.candidateDto.voteResults,typeMismatch.voteResults,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [candidateDto.voteResults,voteResults]; arguments []; default message [voteResults]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'voteResults'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.pk.electionappserver.domain.dto.VoteResultDto' for property 'voteResults[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

And errors in client:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 : [{"timestamp":"2020-01-17T16:17:45.333+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","errors":[{"codes":["typeMismatch.candidateDto.education","typeMismatch.education","typeMismatch.com.pk.electionappserver... (3565 bytes)]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:717)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:443)
    at com.pk.electionappclient.Controller.ClientController.createCandidate(ClientController.java:36)
    at com.pk.electionappclient.Controller.ClientController.addCandidate(ClientController.java:84)
    at com.pk.electionappclient.Controller.admin.NewCandidateController.createNewCandidate(NewCandidateController.java:116)
```

VoteResult entity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity(name = "VoteResults")
public class VoteResult {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERS_ID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ELECTIONS_ID")
    private Election election;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "JOIN_VOTERESULTS_CANDIDATES",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "VOTERESULTS_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CANDIDATES_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")}
    )
    private List<Candidate> candidates;

    private LocalDateTime voteTime;
}
```

ElectionList entity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity(name = "ELECTION_LISTS")
public class ElectionList {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ELECTION_ID")
    private Election election;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONSTITUENCY_ID")
    private Constituency constituency;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Candidate.class,
            mappedBy = "electionList",
            cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<Candidate> candidates;
}
```

ElectoralParty entity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity(name = "ELECTORAL_PARTIES")
public class ElectoralParty {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Candidate.class,
            mappedBy = "electoralParty",
            cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<Candidate> candidates;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ELECTORAL_PROGRAMMES_ID")
    private ElectoralProgramme electoralProgramme;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share you dto code? Also your other entity code.

Comment: The message is pretty clear: you send a parameter, this parameter is a string, and Spring is supposed to create (for example) an ElectionListDto from that string. How could it do that?

Comment: Added rest of these entities. JB Nizet Should I add ObjectMapper in controller from String to Object?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add @RequestBody with @Valid
2. Query param will not work, because it will pass values as string that's why you are getting casting error. This will pass object as object@137462.
   Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36021268/4367186