# How do I connect REST services (inside containers) together, in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, docker-compose

I'm supposed to build a system with individual REST services using docker compose. One of them is a web app where a user can login, and one of them is an authentication service, so I need to connect to the rest authentication service using a post request, and get the confirmation.

This is my authentication service:

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
    private final List<User> users=GetUsers();

    @PostMapping ("/verify")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) {
        for (User u :users)
            if (u.getUsername().equals(username)&&u.getPassword().equals(password))
                return u.getRole();
        return "Invalid Credentials ";

    }
}
```

So, how exactly do I connect from inside the web app code into this service and send a post request?

I know I can send a get using this:

```
String uri = "http://localhost:8080/verify";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
```

How would I send a post? And how would it work inside containers? I know I can link them together inside docker compose, but how do I do it on the code level? Do I replace the `localhost:8080` with `containerName:exposedPort`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, Docker containers are individual Linux virtual machines which means `localhost` inside a Docker container refers to the container itself, **not the host**.

Docker compose has a feature called *DNS resolutions* which basically means you can call other services by their container name or container hash id.

So in your web app, you can call API by `containerName:containerPort` instead of localhost.

For more information, look at [this](https://www.infiproton.com/post/deploying-multi-spring-boot-applications-with-docker-compose) complete implementation.

Comment: this is great thanks !,
but i still cant do a post request, keep getting error 400 bad request , when i try like this :
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  String url = "http://localhost:8080/verify";
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("username", username);
  map.put("password", password);

  ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, map, 
                String.class);

Comment: First, you should not use *localhost*!, then if you want to send body with post request, you should send it throughout `@RequestBody` and not `@RequestParam`, or put parameter inside URL with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36021268/8004901

Comment: im using localhost because im testing outside containers, and yep, i just figured out the @RequestBody a second ago, that was dumb of me, thats a few hours of my life i'll never get back lol, anyway thank you very much , youve been a ton of help.